# ExpressJS: Pipe request directly to another server without storing it in memory

Tags: node.js, express

In order to separate my frontend and backend code I moved the frontend(angular app) to a simple expressJS app. Backend is a much complex Grails app serving only the APIs.

To workaround the CORS(since both these servers would run on different URLs), I'm using this simple code in express app -

```
const express = require("express")
var request = require("request")
const apiServer = process.env.API_URL
app.use("/api/*", function(req, res) {
  var url = apiServer + req.originalUrl
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
});
```

This works well. However, I think it's reading the entire request body in memory before piping it. I don't want that as I have some APIs to upload files and reading those files in express app's memory first would just be time and memory consuming.

I want to keep my express server to be very lightweight as it's only purpose is to serve static resources(angular app)

Comment: Can we not use reverse proxy here for example? Just curious. Something like Caddy?

Comment: You can use reverse proxy with things like Nginx where you can make path-based routing of incoming requests.

Comment: What makes you think that the entire request body is read first? And have you tried replacing `require("request")(url)` with the more basic `https.request(url)`?